# How can get the current state of the material UI component without clicking on any event in react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, material-ui

I am trying to get Material Ui component current values after page reloads or DOM change without clicking on any event. The values are showing from the database.

Basically, I am checking after clicking on the save button if the values are updated or not, if the values are previous values I will return nothing. My function is ready but I am not able to get the current values when the page reloads, I am getting `status` state null.

My UI, the data is showing from the database:
[image]

Select component:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState<string | null>(null); // My state

data.map(details=> {
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Status</InputLabel>
        <Select
            labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
            id="demo-controlled-open-select"
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            onOpen={handleOpen}
            value={details.status || status} // value from DB
            label="Status"
            onChange={(e) => setStatus(details.status || e.target.value)}
        >
            <MenuItem value={'Placed'}>
                <em>Placed</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'Packed'}>Packed</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'Shipped'}>Shipped</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'Delivered'}>Delivered</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'Cancel'}>Cancel</MenuItem>
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
<button onClick={()=>validate (details)}>save</button>
})
```

My function:

```
const validate = (details)=>{
if (details.status !== status) {
        console.log('Do somthing')
    } else {
     console.log('None')
    }
}
```

Comment: Use it ```details.status ?? status```

Comment: Not working, I am able to get the values and display them into the UI but when I page reload I want to check what is the value for this component without clicking any event.

Answer (score -1):

why did you give initial value null to state , try changing that initial value to what you want

Comment: How can I set the current value on my state instead of using null, I am able to get the values after clicking any event but I don't want to click any event the current value will show into the state after the page reload as the values are showing from DB so I want to check what is the value is now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).